# How to access buttons in a UICollectionView from a target function set (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, xcode8

In my View Controller, I have a collection view that, when rendered, displays 3 cells, each of which has a label, and a button. The label displays the name of a color, and the button has a background image that displays a color swatch.

I want it so that whenever you click on one of the buttons, that button gets a dark border around it, while the other buttons get a light border on them, to indicate the clicked-on button as being "selected". Alternately, I could probably do this by changing the image out based on the selected state of the image - but my question remains the same.

**How do I access the other two buttons, to toggle their properties?**

I have a script implemented that allows me to add a border to the button that somebody clicked on - but I cannot figure out how to access the other buttons, in the other cells of the CollectionView to alter their border properties as well.

Here is my source code (with irrelevant/unrelated bits stripped out)

```
class trimSelectorVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var trimSelector: UICollectionView!

    struct trimObject {
        var trimName: String
        var trimButton: String
        var trimID: Int
    }

    var trimArray: [trimObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Chrome", trimButton: "chrome-swatch", trimID: 0))
        trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Gold", trimButton: "gold-swatch", trimID: 1))
        trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Gun Metal", trimButton: "gunmetal-swatch", trimID: 2))

        trimSelector.delegate = self
        trimSelector.dataSource = self
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return trimArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! trimSelectionCell

        //Set the label text
        cell.trimLabel.text = trimArray[indexPath.item].trimName

        //Set the image for the button
        cell.trimButton.setImage(UIImage(named: trimArray[indexPath.item].trimButton), for: UIControlState.normal)

        //Sets a target function for the button
        cell.trimButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedSwatch), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }


    func selectedSwatch(sender: UIButton) {

        //These set the "selected" border to the button you clicked on.
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 2
        sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 71/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.00).cgColor


    }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how to access the other buttons in my "selectedSwatch" function?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can handle this. A `UICollectionView` view has a method `visibleCells()` that returns an array of it's visible cells. You could use that to get pointers to your cells. You would need a way to figure out which one is which. You could use `indexPath(for: UICollectionViewCell)` to figure out the index path of each cell, for example.

Comment: I think this is certainly on the right track. I am able to pull the number of cells in the collection view with this method. How would I use the returned array to drill down to the UIButton inside of the cell?

Something like:
var allCells = trimSelector.visibleCells()
allCells[0].<<What goes here?>>.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black

Comment: Make your collection view cells a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell. Define a prototype cell and connect an outlet in your storyboard. Then cast the cells you get back from the call visibleCells to your custom cell type and use the outlet to find the button(s).

Comment: See this link for an explanation of setting up cell prototypes: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help, but what about if you store the IndexPath on your struct on cellForItemAt method?

You will have:

```
struct trimObject {
    var trimName: String
    var trimButton: String
    var trimID: Int
    var idx : IndexPath
}
```

Then on:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! trimSelectionCell
            ....

 trimArray[indexPath.item].idx = indexPath
     .... 
}
```

And in your selectedSwatch method:

```
func selectedSwatch(sender: UIButton) {

    //These set the "selected" border to the button you clicked on.
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2
    sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 71/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

    if let cell = (sender.superview as? UICollectionViewCell) {

        //Cell with the button selected:
        let idx = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)

        //array of the other objects:
        let allOtherObjects = trimArray.filter { ($0 as! trimObject).idx != idx }

        allOtherObject.forEach({ (trimObj) in
            let cell = collection.cellForItem(at: trimObj.idx)
            //Do whatever yo need to do...
            //cell.trimButton.layer
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its may be to late but still useful for somebody
Swift 4 version:
You can use sender superview as UiCollectionViewCell
* Consider hierarchy of sender in collection view cell

```
func selectedSwatch(sender: UIButton) {
   let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! trimSelectionCell
   //cell.yourbtn 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 class trimSelectorVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
 UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var trimSelector: UICollectionView!

struct trimObject {
    var trimName: String
    var trimButton: String
    var trimID: Int
    var isSelected : String
}

var trimArray: [trimObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Chrome", trimButton: "chrome-swatch", trimID: 0,isSelected : "0"))
    trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Gold", trimButton: "gold-swatch", trimID: 1,isSelected : "0"))
    trimArray.append(trimObject(trimName: "Gun Metal", trimButton: "gunmetal-swatch", trimID: 2,isSelected : "0"))

    trimSelector.delegate = self
    trimSelector.dataSource = self
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return trimArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! trimSelectionCell

    //Set the label text
    cell.trimLabel.text = trimArray[indexPath.item].trimName

    //Set the image for the button
    cell.trimButton.setImage(UIImage(named: 
  trimArray[indexPath.item].trimButton), for: UIControlState.normal)
   if(trimArray[indexPath.item].isSelected == "0"){
   // button not clicked
  // change shadow color of button

    }
   else
    {
   // button  clicked
       cell.trimButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
      cell.trimButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 
       71/255,blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
    }
     // set tag to the button
     cell.trimButton.tag = indexPath.item 

    //Sets a target function for the button
    cell.trimButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(selectedSwatch), 
         for: .touchUpInside)

     return cell
  }


func selectedSwatch(sender: UIButton) {

    //These set the "selected" border to the button you clicked on.

  let index = sender.tag
   for obj in trimArray {
   obj.isSelected = "0"
   }

   trimArray[index].isSelected = "1"

  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

}