# swift 3 - collection view didSelectItemAt indexPath for checkbox

Tags: swift3

I'm generally new to Swift. I have two images, which I want them act like checkbox, first image is unchecked box, second image is checked box, by using `didSelectItemAt indexPath:` in `collection View`, how am I gonna shift between two images when user tapped on that `collectionviewcell`. I'm kinda confused. Heres my code:

```
var buttonCounter = 0 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return faultyType.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "faulty_type_cell", for: indexPath) as! FaultyTypeCollectionViewCell
    cell.faultyTypeLabel.text = faultyType[indexPath.row]
    if buttonCounter == 0{
    cell.checkboxImage.image = UIImage(named: "Checkboxunpicked")
    }
    else if buttonCounter == 1{
    cell.checkboxImage.image = UIImage(named: "Checkboxpicked")
    }
    else if buttonCounter == 2{
    cell.checkboxImage.image = UIImage(named: "Checkboxpicked")
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if indexPath.row == 1{
   buttonCounter = 1
   } 
   if indexPath.row == 2{
   buttonCounter = 2
   }
}
```

Comment: If `buttonCounter` is supposed to be independent for each cell you have to add an appropriate property to your model.

Comment: @vadian Sorry, I don't quite get you. I'm very new here. I thought the buttonCounter can be used to check which cell is being pressed, and then at the cellForItem to change/shift the image?

Comment: Using **one** variable can only change the image of **all** cells simultaneously. To change the image of one cell individually you need to add the state to the `faultyType` object of that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good solution after searching over the net. Heres my solution in which I refer to : [link][How to access buttons in a UICollectionView from a target function set (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835054/how-to-access-buttons-in-a-uicollectionview-from-a-target-function-set-swift-3) Happy coding hunting.

```
var BoxOn = UIImage(named: "Checkboxpicked")
var BoxOff = UIImage(named: "Checkboxunpicked")
var buttonCounter = [Int]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "faulty_type_cell", for: indexPath) as! FaultyTypeCollectionViewCell
    cell.faultyTypeLabel.text = faultyType[indexPath.row]
    cell.checkboxImage.image = BoxOff
    if buttonCounter.contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.checkboxImage.image = BoxOn

    }
    else{
        cell.checkboxImage.image = BoxOff

    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if buttonCounter.contains(indexPath.row){
        let index = buttonCounter.index(of: indexPath.row)
        buttonCounter.remove(at: index!)
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
    else{
        buttonCounter.append(indexPath.row)
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
    print(buttonCounter)
}
```